# Почему в FormData не добавляются данные?

Tags: javascript, ajax, formdata

Имеется такой метод в классе моего плагина.

```
_createQuery(paramsObj, method) {

  if (method === 'GET') {
    let query = '';

    for (let key in paramsObj) {
      query += `${key}=${paramsObj[key]}&`;
    }

    return query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
  } else {
    let data = new FormData();
    for (let key in paramsObj) {
      console.log(key, paramsObj[key]);
      data.append(key, paramsObj[key])
    }

    data.append("username", "Groucho");
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }

}
```

Проблема в следующем: В FormData не добавляются данные, неизвестно по какой причине, `data.append("username", "Groucho");` в это строке явно добавил данные, но когда вывел в консоль `data` получил следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Вывод в консоли выше FormData - это данные, которые я добавляю в  этих строках:

```
console.log(key, paramsObj[key]);
      data.append(key, paramsObj[key])
```

Answer (score 2):

У `FormData` нет свойств, которые могли бы быть выведены в консоль.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/values

```
for (var key of data.keys()) {
   console.log(key, data.get(key));
```